# gRPC server blocked on SendMsg

Tags: go, grpc

We're having an issue where our gRPC streaming server is blocked on `SendMsg` with the following stack trace:

```
google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.(*writeQuota).get(0xc000de4040, 0x32)
    /root/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.46.0/internal/transport/flowcontrol.go:59 +0x74
google.golang.org/grpc/internal/transport.(*http2Server).Write(0xc000bb4680, 0xc000aa6000, {0xc000f2be60, 0x5, 0x5}, {0xc000d6d590, 0x2d, 0x2d}, 0x0)
    /root/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.46.0/internal/transport/http2_server.go:1090 +0x23b
google.golang.org/grpc.(*serverStream).SendMsg(0xc0002785b0, {0xb8f9e0, 0xc000b686c0})
    /root/go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.46.0/stream.go:1530 +0x1cc
```

Our server streams unidirectionally to clients. We had this issue before every 4-6 hours on a node, but after about 15 minutes, the TCP connection would close, the client would reconnect, and streaming would continue as before. We fixed this issue by initializing the server with a keep alive every 10s:

`server := grpc.NewServer(grpc.KeepaliveParams(keepalive.ServerParameters{Time: time.Duration(10) * time.Second, Timeout: 0}))`

and this issue stopped happening for the past two days. Now this issue has been happening for a single node the past 5 hours, and it hasn't gone away.

Here's the output of `ss`:

```
$ ss -ntmp|grep -A 1 9222
ESTAB      0      0      10.192.254.1:9222               10.120.224.70:50380
     skmem:(r0,rb524288,t0,tb524288,f0,w0,o0,bl0,d0)
```

For a server functioning properly on a node, the `t` (wmem_alloc) values and `w` (wmem_queued) values are non-zero. According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551843/199659), this indicates that no packets are queued up for transmit.

I also see keep-alive ACKs sent from the server every 10s. The sequence is:

- server sends `PSH, ACK`
- client immediately responds with `PSH, ACK`
- server sends `ACK` to above
- server sends another `PSH, ACK` after 10s

So the server keep-alive mechanism thinks everything is OK. I don't see any keep-alives from the client. I'll try setting a keep-alive for the client, but why is this problem happening?

Comment: Is the client blocked on RecvMsg?  Is there a proxy in the middle?  If the server is blocked on SendMsg and the connection is responding to keepalives, then the only real answer (besides a bug I've never seen before) is the client isn't receiving, and flow control has filled up.

Comment: There's no proxy in the middle. The client should be blocking on RecvMsg(), but when this problem happened I didn't look at the client side, so I'm not sure if it was stuck on writing to a unbuffered channel or something after RecvMsg(). This problem, though, hasn't happened since we added the client side timeout.

Comment: Client-side keepalives are a good idea no matter what. (We've talked about turning them on by default, but still haven't done it.) I wouldn't expect it to fix this kind of server blocking issue, but maybe I'm just not fully understanding the scenario. If it returns, check the client side, since a blocked server send is most likely flow control filling up.

Comment: What are the options used in `grpcClient.Stream` in your case?

Comment: @zangw Not familiar with that API. On the server, I call `grpc.NewServer()` as described above. On client side, I call `grpc.Dial()` with `grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())` and `grpc.WithKeepaliveParams()`. This problem hasn't happened since we added the client side timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Encounter similar issue with stuck `SendMsg` in `(*writeQuota).get`
Solved by guard SendMsg with Mutex for prevent concurrent calls:

comments on `type ClientStream interface` say:

```
// ... but it is not safe
// to call SendMsg on the same stream in different goroutines. It is also
// not safe to call CloseSend concurrently with SendMsg.
```

Comment: This is isn't an issue for us because the server sends to each client on its own stream.

Answer (score 0):

We added a timeout on the client and this problem hasn't happened since I created this question:

```
grpcConn, err := grpc.Dial(bindAddr,
    grpc.WithKeepaliveParams(keepalive.ClientParameters{Time: time.Duration(10) * time.Second, Timeout: 0}))
```